# Bringing closing value of previous row into starting value of next row

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to being previous row closing value into starting value of next row. I have tried FieldSelecting, RowInserting and FieldDefulting. I am not getting proper value.

Anybody having a better solution for this issue?

Comment: Can you please describe what you want to do with examples and also add the codes you have already tried.

Comment: It would help if you provide some of the examples you have tried

Comment: I am capturing starting and ending value in a grid. If I add a new row, previous row ending value to be assigned to new row starting value.
1-5
5-10
10-15

Comment: I would assume RowInserting/ed should work. In the event you need to select your last row and set the new values. Without examples of what you have tried is hard to provide much more than that.